# This code keeps outputting segmentation fault and I'm not sure why. Any suggestions?

Tags: c++, c++11, segmentation-fault

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{

  int n;

  cin >> n; //currently 7

  while(n > 0)
  {

   for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {

    if(i != 0)
    {
     //cout << i << "/" << n << endl;
     float test = 1.0 * i / n;
     vector<int> total(test);
     sort(total.begin(), total.end());
     cout << total[i] << endl;


    }
   }
   n--;
  }
}
```

Edit: Pasted my whole code. I am just a bit confused about why it is a segmentation error. I checked the internet and I don't think this is any of "Accessing a freed address", "Improper use of scanf", or an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program, what did you see? This is what a debugger is for. If you don't know how to use a debugger this is a good opportunity to learn how to use it to run your program one line at a time, monitor all variables and their values as they change, and analyse your program's logical execution flow. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all bugs in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help.

Comment: Put in a test to make sure n != 0

Comment: The vector declaration needs to be before the loop and the sort after the loop.

Comment: Edited and put my whole code in, sorry about that!

Comment: Please indent it so that it's easier to read

Comment: Sam's suggestion above to run your debugger isn't just a passing comment. It's good advice. Do you know how to use your debugger?

Comment: I currently use an online IDE  and it doesn't have debugger, are there any good ones you suggest?

Comment: Online you have https://www.onlinegdb.com, but you are much MUCH better off downloading a copy of Visual Studio Community edition and working locally. Someday online IDEs will be an effective option, but right now... I remember an old expression about pouring piss out of a boot.

Comment: What online IDE do you use? For offline, I use visual basic community 2019 (on windows), and eclipse on ubuntu (which uses gdb in the background).

Comment: Repl.it, I'll try out onlinegdb.com and then if it doesn't go great I'll proceed with downloading. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like repl.it does have a debugger built in. No idea how good it is.

Comment: Note: when making an example for testing (or posing on stack overflow) remove the user input. If you want to test `n = 7` over and over until you crack the bug, hardcode `int n = 7;` and remove the `cin`s. You want nothing in an example except the minimum possible code needed to reproduce the bug. Often removing the extra noise from the rest of the code is all you need to spot and fix the bug.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: I think repl only has a debugger for python?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you want the program to do?  Is it mean to make 49 vectors like it currently does?  Or is it meant to make 7 vectors each containing a different number of values?

Comment: I'm trying to sort fractions from numerically least to greatest with int n being the denominator. The denominator then decreases until 1.

Comment: I think the advice about using a debugger is useful but in this case not very helpful I think. Sphinx appears to be new to programming and while a debugger would certainly tell them where the segfault was happening, it wouldn't explain why it was happening. To be able to use a debugger efficently requires a level of programming efficency that I don't think Sphinx has reached yet. But I may be wrong of course.

Answer (score 2):

It's a segmentation error because you're accessing unallocated memory.

```
total [i]
```

is never allocated because in the line:-

```
vector<int> total(test);
```

the value of test is always 0, i is always less than n inside the loop so i/n must therefore be zero - the C/C++ languages round integer division to zero (and lots of other languages too); so no elements are added to the vector when it is created (you've used the fill constructor).

Comment: Sorry, I'm a pretty new to this. Does this mean if I change the vector<int> to vector<float> it would work? (still says seg fault). Because if I change it to float, it won't round to 0 right? It would be a decimal.

Comment: ***Does this mean if I change the vector<int> to vector<float> it would work?*** No it won't work.

Comment: @Sphinxtheriddlemaster The reason it won't work is that the constructor for std::vector you are using fills the vector with "test" copies of the number 0, and the constructor takes an integer parameter so when you pass a float smaller than zero it is converted to an integer (which is 0) and then is used to fill the vector with zero items.